# List matches of page.search_for() with PyMuPDF

Tags: python, pymupdf

I'm writing a script to highlight text from a list of quotes in a PDF. The quotes are in the list `text_list`. I use this code to highlight the text in the PDF:

```
import fitz
#Load Document
doc = fitz.open(filename)

#Iterate over pages
for page in doc:
# iterate through each text using for loop and annotate
    for i, text in enumerate(text_list):
        rl = page.search_for(text, quads = True)
        page.add_highlight_annot(rl)
# Print how many results were found
print(str(i) + " instances highlighted in pdf")
```

I now want to get a list of the quotes that were not found and highlighted and was wondering if there is any simple way to get a list of the matches `page.search_for` found (or of those quotes it didn't find).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of hit rectangles / quads `rl` will be empty if nothing was found.
I suggest you check `if rl == []:` and depend adding highlights on this as well as adding the respective text to some `no_hit` list.

Probably better the other way round:
Your text *list* better should be a Python `set`. If a text was ever found put it in another, `found_set`. At end of processing subtract (set difference) the found set from `text_list` set.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me. Because the script iterates over the pages (and thus rl is empty quite often] I slightly modified your solution and appended text to the no_hit list if `rl != []`, which I then compared against text_list.